# Custom iOS Push with node-pushserver

Tags: node.js, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to insert a custom iOS push notification using node-pushserver lib...

The format that I want is:

```
"aps": {
        "alert": "joetheman",
        "sound": "default"
    },
    "message": "Some custom message for your app",
    "id": 1234
```

The format that I have:

```
 "ios": {
                "badge": 0,
                "alert": message.message,
                "sound": "soundName"  
              }
```

How can I do that?

Comment: i have a same problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"ios": {
                "badge": 0,
                "alert": message.message,
                "sound": "soundName",
                "payload" : {
                     "message": "Some custom message for your app",
                     "id": 1234
                }
        }
```